# Django use templatetag API Wrapper

Tags: python, django, forms, rest

I'm writing a custom API wrapper for automating stuff on multiple devices having a REST API. Authentication to these devices is via csrf token.
I'm struggling making a connection via form input using the devices API as custom tag. In addition im not really sure if this is the right approach to start a project like this.

**app/views.py**

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    template = loader.get_template('app/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def webbase_html(request):
    context = {}
    load_template = request.path.split('/')[-1]
    template = loader.get_template('app/' + load_template)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))`
```

**templatetags/device_handler.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
from app.templatetags.device_api import DeviceAPI
from requests.exceptions import ConnectTimeout

@register.simple_tag
def login_device(host, username, password):
    dev = DeviceAPI()
    try:
        dev.login(host, username, password)
        hname = dev.get_host_name() 
        return hname
    except ConnectTimeout as error:
        return error
```

**templatetags/device_api.py** Looks like this: (Snippet)

```
class DeviceAPI(object):
def __init__(self):
    self._https = True
    self._version = "Version is set when logged"
    self._session = requests.session()  # use single session
    self._session.verify = False

def formatresponse(self, res):
    resp = json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8')
    return resp

def update_cookie(self):
    for cookie in self._session.cookies:
        if cookie.name == 'ccsrftoken':
            csrftoken = cookie.value[1:-1]  # token stored as a list
            self._session.headers.update({'X-CSRFTOKEN': csrftoken})

def login(self, host, username, password):
    self.host = host
    if self._https is True:
        self.url_prefix = 'https://' + self.host
    else:
        self.url_prefix = 'http://' + self.host
    url = self.url_prefix + '/logincheck'
    res = self._session.post(
        url,
        data='username=' + username + '&secretpass=' + password + "&ajax=1", timeout=10)

    if b"1document.location=\"/ng/prompt?viewOnly&redir" in res.content:
        self.update_cookie()
    else:
        raise Exception('login failed')
```

**template/connect.html**

```
{% extends "app/base_site.html" %}
{% block title %} test {% endblock title %}
{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block content %}
{% load my_class %}
 <div class="right_col" role="main">
    <h3>Connected to</h3>
    <p>{% login_device "192.168.100.1" "user" "password" %}</p>   
 </div>

{% endblock content %}
{% block javascripts %}
  {{ block.super}}
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

The connect html would return the devices Hostname. But I doubt this is a legit approach doing this kind of REST interaction.
So Id like to know what approach would be best practice to interact with the devices API.

Related to this construct, how would I call login_device with input Forms the right way?